# How to find the closest (2nd closest, 3rd closest...) value in Stata

Tags: stata, matching, closest

I face the following issue in Stata15 / ca. 5,000 observations, with the following data given:

```
n  Company_ID  Revenue Industry_Class  Fiscal_Year
1  100         5000    11              2018
2  200         4000    11              2018
3  300         3000    11              2017
4  400         2500    22              2018
5  500         3500    11              2018
```

I would like to create new variables `Peer_1` and `Peer_2`. The code should work as follows:

1. for `Peer_1`: Give me the `Company_ID` for the firm that is **closest** to the revenue in the respective row, if `Fiscal_Year` and `Industry_Class` are the same.
2. for `Peer_2`: Give me the `Company_ID` for the firm that is **2nd closest** to the revenue in the respective row, if `Fiscal_Year` and `Industry_Class` are the same.
3. If the code does not find a peer in the same `Fiscal_Year` and `Industry_Class`, assign "N/A"

For example, `Company_ID` "100" has a revenue of 5,000. The closest firm in the the same class and year is firm "200" with a revenue of 4,000. The 2nd closest firm in the same class and year is firm "500" with a revenue of 3,500.

The output should look like this:

```
 n  Company_ID  Revenue Industry_Class  Fiscal_Year  Peer_1  Peer_2
 1  100         5000    11              2018         200     500
 2  200         4000    11              2018         500     100
 3  300         3000    11              2017         N/A     N/A
 4  400         2500    22              2018         N/A     N/A
 5  500         3500    11              2018         200     100
```

Is there a possibility to code this efficiently in Stata? I stumbled upon functions such as `psmatch` or `nnmatch`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the commands (in Stata they are not functions) `psmatch` or `nnmatch` either. This is a crude algorithm, looping over firms and finding the observations (in Stata not called rows) in the same year and class that have smallest absolute difference between revenue and revenue for that firm.

I haven't assumed that `n` corresponds one to one with the firm identifier, even though that is true in the data example.

Stata doesn't support `N/A` as a code for numeric missings. You could have that as a string value, but Stata gives it no special meaning.

If two or more firms have the same such smallest absolute difference, no special action is taken and which is identified as Peer 1 and Peer 2 will be arbitrary.

```
clear 
input n  Company_ID  Revenue Industry_Class  Fiscal_Year  Peer_1  Peer_2
 1  100         5000    11              2018         200     500
 2  200         4000    11              2018         500     100
 3  300         3000    11              2017         .       .
 4  400         2500    22              2018         .       . 
 5  500         3500    11              2018         200     100
 end 

 gen wanted_1 = . 
 gen wanted_2 = . 
 gen diff = . 
 gen ref = . 
 egen id = group(Company_ID)
 su id, meanonly 

 * loop over firms 
 quietly forval i = 1/`r(max)' { 
    * look up its class (should be constant) 
    * summarize leaves r(min) and r(max) in its wake 
    * if result is constant r(min) and r(max) will be identical 
    su Industry_Class if id == `i', meanonly 
    if r(min) != r(max) { 
        di as err "id `i'" is in two or more classes" 
    }
    else { 
        local class = r(min)

        * this firm's revenue is the reference revenue, different in each year 
        replace ref = Revenue if id == `i'
        bysort Fiscal_Year (ref): replace ref = ref[1] 

        * care only about other firms, same class and same year 
        replace diff = cond(id != `i' & Industry_Class == `class', abs(Revenue - ref), .) 
        * sort on differences to get peers 
        bysort Fiscal_Year (diff) : replace wanted_1 = Company_ID[1] if id == `i' & diff[1] < . 
        by Fiscal_Year (diff) : replace wanted_2 = Company_ID[2] if id == `i' & diff[2] < .
    }
 } 

 drop id diff ref 

 sort Industry_Class Fiscal_Year 

 list, sepby(Industry_Class Fiscal_Year)

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | n   Compan~D   Revenue   Indust~s   Fiscal~r   Peer_1   Peer_2   wanted_1   wanted_2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 3        300      3000         11       2017        .        .          .          . |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  2. | 2        200      4000         11       2018      500      100        500        100 |
  3. | 1        100      5000         11       2018      200      500        200        500 |
  4. | 5        500      3500         11       2018      200      100        200        100 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. | 4        400      2500         22       2018        .        .          .          . |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `n` is the original order (otherwise, another one could be generated). In assuming that, below is another solution with `joinby`.

```
clear
input byte n int(Company_ID Revenue) byte Industry_Class int Fiscal_Year
1 100 5000 11 2018
2 200 4000 11 2018
3 300 3000 11 2017
4 400 2500 22 2018
5 500 3500 11 2018
end

tempfile a
save `a', replace

ren (n Company_ID Revenue) Peer_=
joinby using `a'
replace Peer_Company_ID =. if Peer_n == n 

gen dif = abs(Peer_Revenue - Revenue) if Peer_n != n
bys n (dif): gen j = _n
drop if j > 2

drop Peer_n Peer_Revenue dif
reshape wide Peer_Company_ID, i(n Company_ID Revenue Industry_Class Fiscal_Year) j(j)
```

Comment: This is nice. Not attempting to subtract any niceness, but I have always been wary of `joinby` as liable to produce very big files from big files. That said, my solution is ugly in just looping over firms.

Comment: Yes, Proffesor Nick, `joinby`'s effectiveness would be disapeared for bigfiles. Meanwhile, loop is always a feasible and proper solution.